# NSIndexPath can never be nil, comparison isn't allowed

Tags: swift, uitableview

Im trying to see if the user presses a cell in a table view, but i cannot compare it to nil? How would i check if a cell has not been pressed? This is the handler when the user does a long press on the table view

```
func handleLongPress(gestureRecognizer: UILongPressGestureRecognizer) {
    let p: CGPoint = gestureRecognizer.locationInView(self.tableView)
    let indexPath: NSIndexPath = self.tableView.indexPathForRowAtPoint(p)!
    if indexPath == nil{

    }
    else if gestureRecognizer.state == .Began {
        print(indexPath.row)
    }

}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should not force unwrap and then check for `nil` - that would crash your app. What you should do is: drop the unwrap and then compare!

```
func handleLongPress(gestureRecognizer: UILongPressGestureRecognizer) {
    let point = gestureRecognizer.locationInView(self.tableView)
    let indexPath = self.tableView.indexPathForRowAtPoint(point)
    if let touchedPath = indexPath {
        if gestureRecognizer.state == .Began {
            print(touchedPath.row)
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: You're mixing things. There is a **compiler** error which he is talking about, the compiler is saying *you have already forcefully unwrapped me I would never be `nil` and therefore I won't ever enter that line, ever! Having that said I may crash ( as you mentioned) where you 'forcefully' attempted to unwrap me.* I think your wording is confusing and you're not separating the issues

Comment: @Honey the statement about crashing was regarding the force unwrap alone. Them checking for nil obviously is a compiler error which is what brought OP here in the first place